# Computer only accesses the internet when using a static DNS ip

Tags: dns, home-networking, dd-wrt, nat, static-ip

My setup is wall-> Zyxel p-870h-51a VDSL2 modem -> DD-WRT router.

The issue is that the modem has connected to the internet, but the computer is unable to.

This is resolved if on the individual computers you assign a static DNS ip of 8.8.8.8/8.8.4.4.

This isn't ideal, as you need to set every computer up this way, and also our Wii won't connect.

Any ideas how to resolve this?

**Update:** I asked a [new question here](https://superuser.com/questions/736165/modem-not-assigning-dns) regarding this issue, which has solved it. DD-WRT was a red herring, as the issue was with the modem. The issue was with NAT, setting the modem to use Full Cone NAT solved it.

Answer (score 0):

The instructions you used are for a wireless AP and assume that there is another router in the network to provide the network details, specifically those you have to enter manually now. Obviously there isn't another router in your network which could distribute those settings so the instructions are not suited for your use case.

I'm also quite certain that the device you find unter 192.168.1.1 is your WRT and not your modem. The WRT is the router of your subnet, and if you want your local machines to automatically receive network settings, including name server settings, *you must activate and configure DHCP.*

Regarding your Iphone I can't say what's going on, I don't have access to any Apple hardware. It sounds like Apple is falling back to a Apple DNS server if you have IP networking and there is no other DNS server provided. Maybe it's more sinister and Apple always queries its own DNS server and uses provided DNS servers only as forwarders for local domains. I don't know but would be interested to know more.

Comment: Hmmm, one of my friends iPhones connected automatically, but anothers also required the DNS configuration.

Comment: Maybe your friend has set up a custom DNS server on his phone. That would explain it.

Comment: Thanks for the advice btw - I do need to get my head around various home networking terminology, eg the diffence between a router and an access point, what DCHP is etc...

Comment: Re: 'Anothe router in the network'. The ZyXEL is a modem-router.

Comment: Hmmm one clue here was that I had plugged the connected a LAN port of the ZyXEL modem-router with the WAN port of the DD-WRT router. I"ve remedied this, but 192.168.1.1 still directly accesses the ZyXEL.

Comment: The DD-WRT is a bit of a red herring for this issue, as plugging directly into the ZyXEL modem also has this issue.